# How to fix a panel of a splitPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to know how to fix the JPanel2(in my imported image) to the right side of the application. I am using a JSplitPane so I can resize my JPanel2 with the splitter. When I resize the window, I want the JPanel2 to keep the same size as I set before and the JPanel1 to stretch. For example:

### [image: JSplitPane]

Does anyone have an idea ? Thx.

Comment: Why would you "fix" one panel when you're using a `JSplitPane`, that kind of doesn't make sense. In this case, I'd consider just using a `GridBagLayout` or even a `BorderLayout`. Having said all that, you code doesn't even include a `JSplitPane`. I'd recommend avoiding `setMaximum/PreferredSize`, but that's me.  Also `jPanel1` should be added to the `CENTRE` position

Comment: panel1 should go to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout if you want it to get all the remaining space.

Comment: Edited my question. Thx :)

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to adjust the size of the left panel only on window resize. You might also want to anchor the jSplitPanel to the window size.

To anchor the jSplitPanel to the window size, left click on the jSplitPanel, go to Auto Resizing and check Horizontal and Vertical.

To adjust the size of the left panel only, you want to add
  `jSplitPanel.setResizeWeight(0);`
In the window init().